# Xamarin.Forms проблема с доступом к файлам Assets

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Имеется решение Xamarin.Forms, которое состоит из двух проектов QmsPointXamarin и QmsPointXamarin.Android.
Вопрос: каким образом можно получить доступ к файлу Assets/sound/begin.mp3 проекта QmsPointXamarin.Android из файла HybridWebViewPagе.xaml.cs проекта QmsPointXamarin?

[image: доступ к Assets]

Попытка использовать `string soundPath = "file:///android_asset/sounds/begin.mp3";` доступа к файлу не даёт.

Comment: Я использую Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer и просто указываю в методе Load("begin.mp3") Для файла нужно указать BuildAction: AndroidAsset

Answer (score 0):

Для воспроизведения звукового файла из Assets необходимо использовать механизм DependencyCervice:

1. В проекте QmsPointXamarin определяем интерфейс IAudioService:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace QmsPointXamarin.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAudioService
    {
        Task PlayAudioFile(string fileName);
    }
}
```

2. В проект QmsPointXamarin.Droid добавляем класс AudioServiceImplementation, реализующий интерфейс IAudioService:

```
using QmsPointXamarin.Interfaces;
using QmsPointXamarin.Droid.Implementations;
using Android.Media;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioServiceImplementation))]
namespace QmsPointXamarin.Droid.Implementations
{
    public class AudioServiceImplementation : IAudioService
    {
        private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
        public async Task PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            _mediaPlayer.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                _mediaPlayer.Start();
            };
            await _mediaPlayer.SetDataSourceAsync(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            _mediaPlayer.Prepare();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Для вызова метода PlayAudioFile в проекте QmsPointXamarin используем DependencyService.Get:

```
IAudioService audioService = DependencyService.Get<IAudioService>();
audioService.PlayAudioFile("sounds/begin.mp3");
```